# How to distinguish mass concentration and density?

Tags: concentration, terminology, reference-request, notation

I am writing a proof where I have to mention both with density and of a material and mass concentration (mass/volume) of a material.

I am using the letter $\rho$ to represent density, and I didn't want to abuse the same symbol for concentration because it will make the whole proof much harder to follow. I would also prefer to avoid subscripts as the only distinguishable element.

What other symbol or syntax should I use to distinguish density from mass concentration of a material?

Comment: Will $c\mathstrut$ do?

Comment: @IvanNeretin If that's a accepeted convention, yes... but I actually have other constants named c :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to IUPAC's Green Book [1], both $γ$ and $ρ$ can be employed to denote mass concentration. Fragment of a table from the section 2.10 GENERAL CHEMISTRY [1, p. 48]:

> $$
> \begin{array}{llll}
> \hline
> \text{Name} & \text{Symbol} & \text{Definition} & \text{SI unit} \\
> \hline
> \ldots \\
> \text{mass concentration, (mass density)} & γ, ρ & γ_\ce{B} = m_\ce{B}/V & \pu{kg m-3} \\
> \ldots \\
> \hline
> \end{array}
> $$
>
> […]  In polymer science the word “concentration” and the symbol $c$ is normally used for mass concentration.

Also, from [the SI Brochure](https://www.bipm.org/en/publications/si-brochure/), [[2, p. 139](https://www.bipm.org/utils/common/pdf/si-brochure/SI-Brochure-9-EN.pdf#page=25)]:

> $$
> \begin{array}{lll}
> \hline
> \text{Derived quantity} & \text{Typical symbol} & \text{Derived unit expressed} \\
>   & \text{of quantity} & \text{in terms of base units} \\
> \hline
> \ldots \\
> \text{mass concentration} & γ, ρ & \pu{kg m-3} \\
> \ldots \\
> \hline
> \end{array}
> $$

#### References

1. IUPAC “Green Book” Quantities, Units, and Symbols in Physical Chemistry, 3rd ed.; Cohen, R. E., Mills, I., Eds.; IUPAC Recommendations; *RSC Pub: Cambridge, UK*, **2007**. ISBN 978-0-85404-433-7.
2. BIPM. L*e Système International d’unitès / The International System of Units (“The SI Brochure”)*, 9th ed.; Bureau international des poids et mesures: Sèvres, **2019**.

Comment: Thanks. I never saw it before, but in IUPAC I'll trust and I shall use $\gamma$.