# Meaning of mass concentration "units" % m/v

Tags: aqueous-solution, concentration, notation, units

> In a saline solution that is 5.750% (m/v) potassium iodide $(\ce{KI}),$ there are:
>
> **a**) 5.750 mL $\ce{KI}$ per 100.0 mL $\ce{H2O}$
> **b**) 575.0 mg $\ce{KI}$ per 10.00 mL of $\ce{KI}$ solution
> **c**) 5.750 g $\ce{KI}$ per 100.0 g $\ce{H2O}$
> **d**) 5.750 g $\ce{KI}$ per 100.0 g of $\ce{KI}$ solution
> **e**) 5.750 g $\ce{KI}$ per 100.0 mL of $\ce{H2O}$

I figured it should be **e** because for the equation of $(\text{m/v})\%$ is

$$(\text{m/v})\% = \frac{\text{mass solute (g)}}{\text{volume solution (ml)}}$$
and it's $\pu{g/100 mL},$ but it's not the correct answer.

Comment: 5.75g of some salt isnt going to increase the volume of 100ml solution. if it does the change will be negligible.

Comment: But 100 mL of ........  ?

Comment: You wrote it yourself in the divider, "volume solution (ml)", and there is only one option for that (support your choice by calculating the concentration; consult [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_concentration_(chemistry)#Units) if in doubt).

Comment: The funny thing is that the correct answer is not available (unless posing Delta V zero and rounding 105 to 100). Totally unsuitable for a multi choice test. Acceptable for an oral exercise at the board/desk.

Comment: @Alchimista **b** looks fine to me without any approximations, why do you think there is no correct answer? An exercise looks decent to me and trains attentiveness well.

Comment: The fact is that writing "there are" means there are. Of course I understand what you mean, but we never write down = instead of ~ . Moreover the use of four digits is disturbing in this context. The solution isn't even in the ppm range, a case that I would have found less or no disturbing. ...

Comment: @Alchimista I suspect "*there are $x$ **grams***", that's what they mean. I also don't see the problem with four digits, there is no mention how the mass has been determined (and it's really irrelevant for answering).

Comment: The task and the choice from given asnwers is really trivial. I do not understand the big deal @Alchemista makes about it.  The author has made a trivial trick with potentially misleading formulation of the correct answer.

Comment: @Andselisk sorry but the problem is that the solution is given at 5.750 %, you are using a circular thinking. The point is that either you know the KI mass at the four digit, or the percent concentration. Writing down both with the same precision exclude the standard approximation. Which by the way are correct in the ppm range. I can discern hundred grams from 105 g almost in my kitchen. That we use this conc. just for quenching or provide an environment is another story. In fact, we prepare 5% percent stuff, not 5.000%. The quiz in my opinion is really wrong, though answerable for the delight

Comment: .... of everyone.

Comment: YES B IS CORRECT. @Andselisk I miss the first line!  I think I must delete my comments not because ashamed but not to confuse op or future reader. Indeed I was attentive :))

Comment: @Alchimista It's up to you, really, but I see no harm in leaving your comments (the whole section is likely to be moved to the chat, so …:D).

Comment: Yes @Poutnik. Obviously the deal would have existed without the correct answer. I have taken the rest as minimizing that potential but not factual situation. Didn't see b) refers to ml of slt.

Answer (score 3):

Since the question raised a discussion in the comments, I guess it won't hurt putting up a brief summarizing answer.

Notation % m/v, as you might've guessed, refers to the ratio between the **m**ass and the **v**olume, or, more precisely, [mass concentration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_concentration_(chemistry)) $ρ_i$ (sometimes denoted as $γ_i$ [1, p. 48] to distinguish from density, see [How to distinguish mass concentration and density?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/117946/41328)):

$$ρ_i = \frac{m_i}{V}$$

where $m_i$ is the mass of solute and $V$ is the volume of solution, suggesting the SI unit $\pu{kg m-3}.$
Where does percent in % m/v come from?
Quoting [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_concentration_(chemistry)#Units):

> In biology, the "%" symbol is sometimes incorrectly used to denote mass concentration, also called "mass/volume percentage." A solution with 1 g of solute dissolved in a final volume of 100 mL of solution would be labeled as "1%" or "1% m/v" (mass/volume). The notation is mathematically flawed because the unit "%" can only be used for dimensionless quantities.

So, in order to account for this percentage “unit”, one should normalize the mass concentration to the mass of solute in grams in 100 mL of solution.
This can be done in one's head in most cases, but you must watch out for the units.

In this particular example, only option **b** satisfy the definition of the % m/v quantity we are expressing since only **b** lists *volume of KI solution*.
Let's check the math.
Since $\pu{575.0 mg} = \pu{0.5750 g},$ there is $\pu{0.5750 g}$ $\ce{KI}$ per $\pu{10.00 mL}$ of $\ce{KI}$ solution, and normalizing to $\pu{100 mL}$ we indeed obtain the aforementioned concentration:

$$ρ_\ce{KI} = \frac{\pu{0.5750 g}}{\pu{10.00 mL}} = \frac{\pu{5.750 g}}{\pu{100.0 mL}} = 5.750\%~(\text{m/v})$$

The exercise really just requires to pay more attention and follow the analytical chemistry definitions.

#### References

1. *IUPAC “Green Book” Quantities, Units, and Symbols in Physical Chemistry*, 3rd ed.; Cohen, R. E., Mills, I., Eds.; IUPAC Recommendations; RSC Pub: Cambridge, UK, **2007**. ISBN 978-0-85404-433-7.